Snapped windows getting resized in XFCE
I'm running Xubuntu 22.04 LTS with xfce 4.16.
Kernel is 5.15.0-101-generic (not sure this is relevant).
I can snap windows from within XFCE to either side of the screen using super + right arrow, super + left arrow etc. They initially look good like this but, after some use, resize spontaneously slightly so that the very bottom of the window falls of the screen.
This isn't an issue with most apps but is really annoying with the terminal as you can no longer see the line that you're typing on.
Has anyone else experienced this? I couldn't find anything online (but it's quite difficult to describe so may not have appeared with my chosen search terms).

When you open a second tab in the terminal, the tab bar appears and increases the window height.

Thanks @HolyBlackCat, this happens because opening a new tab in a previously single-tab window resizes the window automatically, increasing the height. Annoyingly obvious when you know :)
Two potential fixes:

open a new tab before snapping the window to either side of the screen
adjust configuration for xfce4-terminal to always show the tab bar

For the second option, the setting that is required is MiscAlwaysShowTabs=TRUE in ~/.config/xfce4/terminal/terminalrc:
sed -i 's/MiscAlwaysShowTabs=FALSE/MiscAlwaysShowTabs=TRUE/g' \
    ~/.config/xfce4/terminal/terminalrc

should do it. Then reopen your xfce4-terminal.
